# Java overloaded methods and null parameter

Tags: java, java-8

I have the two following overloaded methods:

```
public static void test(Integer n) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}

public static void test(Number n) {
    System.out.println("Number");
}
```

when I invoke the test method with `null`, something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test(null);
}
```

I receive:

```
Integer
```

Could you please explain why do I receive the `Integer` and not a compilation error because it is really not obvious with `null` parameter what `test` method should be executed?

Comment: IIRC this is covered in the JLS, 15.2.mumbleish

Comment: It chooses the method with the most specific type. In this case `Integer`, because it's a subtype of `Number`. If you add another method that takes a `Double`, you will get a compile error because the call is ambigious.

Comment: Because for overloading must be choosen the most specific method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), and `Integer` is more specific, that `Number`

Comment: The best thing to do, is completely avoid doing things like this.  Check for nulls on input, use different method signatures or inheritance so it is clear what you want to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *<null>* type is an acceptable value for both `Integer` and `Number` so both are possible overloads.

Java then chooses the most specific overload.

Since `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, it is more specific.

See [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the three phases of applicability testing, then **the most specific one is chosen**, as specified in section [§15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

And the relative specificity of `Integer` and `Number` falls out of this rather opaque spec language in §15.12.2.5:

> - m2 is not generic, and m1 and m2 are applicable by strict or loose invocation, and where m1 has formal parameter types S1, ..., Sn and m2 has formal parameter types T1, ..., Tn, **the type Si is more specific than Ti for argument ei** for all i (1 ≤ i ≤ n, n = k).